# Errors in attempting to format dates in Excel

Tags: excel

I am having a small problem with splitting up dates using the Excel delimiter tool.  Usually I am able to either do some quick format changes to 'Short Date' or delimit with a non-existent delimiter in order to use the DMY option to standardize format.  However, I have exhausted both of those options and nonetheless the dates appear to be mismatched.  That is, suppose I take RIGHT(A1,4) in order to obtain only the year for each cell containing a date.  Some of these give me the correct year e.g. 1973 and some give me a large number e.g. 6340.  Why might this be happening?

Comment: Some example data would be *extremely* helpful in assisting you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In excel dates stored as numbers: e.g. `01/01/2013` is `41275` and `Right(A1,4)` gives you `1275`. Try this one instead:

```
=YEAR(A1)
```

or

```
=TEXT(A1,"yyyy")
```

first formula returns *number* `2013` and second formula returns *text* `"2013"`

**UPD:**

as follow up from comments, since dates can be stored *as text or as dates*, this one works:

```
=RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy;@"),4)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the first gives me a #VALUE error or the year 1905 and the second gives 1972 and in the second case 11/17/1988

Comment: how your dates are stored? as text or as dates?

Comment: I worry that they might be stored as both, but I have used the dropdown menu and the delimiter trick to try to make them all date formatted.  Trying to take just the year was my third option.

Comment: try this one: `=RIGHT(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy;@"),4)`

Comment: That seems to have worked perfectly, thank you!